# Significado de "rémora" en este pasaje de "Cien años de soledad"

Tags: significado, significado-en-contexto

En *Cien años de soledad*, de Gabriel García Márquez, he leído este pasaje que describe cómo un grupo de hombres encuentran un antiguo galeón español (negrita mía):

> Cuando despertaron, ya con el sol alto, se quedaron pasmados de fascinación. Frente a ellos, rodeado de helechos y palmeras, blanco y polvoriento en la silenciosa luz de la mañana, estaba un enorme galeón español. Ligeramente volteado a estribor, de su arboladura intacta colgaban las piltrafas escuálidas del velamen, entre jarcias adornadas de orquídeas. El casco, cubierto con una tersa coraza de **rémora** petrificada y musgo tierno, estaba firmemente enclavado en un suelo de piedras. Toda la estructura parecía ocupar un ámbito propio, un espacio de soledad y de olvido, vedado a los vicios del tiempo y a las costumbres de los pájaros. En el interior, que los expedicionarios exploraron con un fervor sigiloso, no había nada más que un apretado bosque de flores.

No entiendo el significado de "rémora" en el contexto del texto. Las dos acepciones que aparecen en el [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/r%C3%A9mora), un pez y una persona o cosa que retrasa o dificulta algo, no me parecen adecuadas. He buscado también en el [*Diccionario de americanismos*](https://www.asale.org/damer/r%C3%A9mora), pero no contiene la voz "rémora". ¿Alguien lo sabría explicar?

Comment: Pero precisamente la definición del DLE indica las características del pez que te pueden servir para interpretar esto como metáfora ("...para adherirse fuertemente a los objetos flotantes").

Comment: @Rodrigo:    Sí, puedes tener razón. Quizás lo que vieron, aún estar petrificado, recordaba al comportamiento de las rémoras cuando se adhieren a algo, como se ve, por ejemplo, en esta [fotografía](https://www.shutterstock.com/es/image-photo/whale-shark-swimming-under-water-ocean-123660703). Lo curioso es que se trataba de personas que no habían visto nunca el mar.

Answer (score 2):

**REMORA**

---

[image]

---

En la obra "*El ahogado más hermoso del mundo*” también del escritor Colombiano Gabriel García Márquez, el tercero de los cuentos del libro "La increíble y triste historia de la cándida Eréndira y de su abuela desalmada" (1972), utilizará igualmente la expresión, "**Coraza de Rémora**", "*... porque su piel estaba revestida de una coraza de rémora y de lodo...*" refiriéndose a alguien al que costaba identificar, y que apareciendo cadáver, se halló cubierto completamente, por muchos peces rémora.

Por tanto, en el caso de la obra "*Cien años de soledad*" (1967), "coraza de rémora", está haciendo referencia al casco del barco, el cual se encuentra totalmente cubierto o envuelto por una capa de "peces rémora" que imposibilitan verlo o identificarlo correctamente y que en esa visión, forman una coraza compacta ya petrificada con el casco que se intuye, pero al que no ven o no son capaces de identificar adecuadamente, debido precisamente a la cantidad o magnitud de "esqueletos de peces rémora" adheridos y petrificados en él.

- "*el casco cubierto de una tersa coraza de rémora petrificada...*"
- el casco cubierto de una brillante capa de esqueletos de peces rémora, convertidos ya, en material endurecido ...

*La rémora es un pez que se adhiere a otros peces o cosas que floten en el agua para alimentarse o protegerse y que suelen adherirse a los cascos de los barcos, contándose casos en que la capacidad y la cantidad de rémoras fijadas al casco era tal, que por su volumen, podían detener algunas naves*.